# How to @Autowired a concrete implementation of a service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following situation:

```
public interface ServiceAura extends Serializable { }

@Service
public class ServiceA implements ServiceAura {
    ....
}

@Service
public class ServiceB implements ServiceAura {
    ....
}
```

Now from the controller I need to call both of them by separate:

```
@Path("")
@Controller
public class ServiciosAuraPortalRESTfulService {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceAura srvA;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceAura srvB;

}
```

I have read about @Qualified, is this the only way? How can I archive this?

Comment: What's wrong with Qualifier?

Comment: alternative would be using the implementation-class instead of the interface when declaring the attribute

Comment: If you want to use Spring DI to inject different implementations of the same interface then using qualifiers is a recommended way to do that. 

To enhance readability, you can come up with more descriptive qualifiers, read this article https://memorynotfound.com/creating-and-configuring-custom-qualifier-annotation/

Comment: Nothing, I just found https://www.boraji.com/spring-4-qualifier-annotation-example and it has too many Qualified. Is this realy necesary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. You can use `@Qualifier("ServiceA")` to specify which implementation you want to autowire.

```
@Path("")
@Controller
public class ServiciosAuraPortalRESTfulService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ServiceA")
    private ServiceAura srvA;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ServiceB")
    private ServiceAura srvB;
```

}

On the service itself, you can use the annotation `@Primary` to specify which one is the default implementation that you want.

Alternatively, you can use the application context to retrieve a specific bean. You'll need to autowire the `ApplicationContext` class and then retrieve it with `ServiceAura srvA = context.getBean(ServiceA.class);`

Comment: @Qualifier("ServiceA") will know that im refearing to ServiceA?

Comment: yeah I guess he already knew that ;) he asked if there is another way

Comment: @Qualifier will check the ApplicationContext, will pull the beans from the HashMap and filter them by implementing class name. Honestly, I've never looked at the implementation details but that's the behaviour that this annotation has. The name is created by the Spring naming conventions, but you can override it in the `@Service` annotation `@Service("myNewBeanValue"`),

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this.
The first way is using @Qualifier annotation as you've stated.

```
@Path("")
@Controller
public class ServiciosAuraPortalRESTfulService {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("serviceA")
  private ServiceAura srvA;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("serviceB") 
  private ServiceAura srvB;
}
```

Your services should be defined like this:

```
 @Service
 @Qualifier("serviceA") 
 public class ServiceA implements ServiceAura {
   ....
 }

 @Service
 @Qualifier("serviceB")
 public class ServiceB implements ServiceAura {
   ....
 }
```

Another way is to create interfaces that extend interface `ServiceAura`

```
interface ServiceAInterface extends ServiceAura {
}

class ServiceA implements ServiceAInterface {}

 .... // the same for service B
```

And then in code:

```
public class ServiciosAuraPortalRESTfulService {

  @Autowired
  ServiceAInterface serviceA;
}
```